# Mammal producing spider venom

Tags: science-based, biology, zoology

Could a human be genetically engineered to produce a less fatal form of the Brazilian Wandering Spider’s Venom? I have been told that many things that insects can do do not function in humans for various reasons, so I would like to know if this could work.

Comment: can you provide some details about this spider and its venom? not everybody knows them by heart.

Comment: Two issues: venom is injected, and there has to be a an organ to create and store the venom.  Thus, there would have to be significant changes to the human skull/upper jaw.

Comment: @L.Dutch oh sorry, I would rather not go into detail, because I don't know how many kids are on the site so here is a link, https://animalcorner.co.uk/animals/brazilian-wandering-spider/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, yes this would be possible.

The neurotoxin in question ([PhTx3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneutria_nigriventer_toxin-3)) is a [peptide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peptide), which means that almost any organsim can make it as long as it has the right DNA available. One difficulty with this problem is that the neurotoxins need the correct [Cystein-Cystein bonds](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structural_Biochemistry/Chemical_Bonding/_Disulfide_bonds) to fold correctly, which probably also prohibits people from making them from bacteria ([Description](https://febs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1016/0014-5793%2892%2981318-G) of how the toxins where obtained to analyse them).

Now to the more important part: why would you want this?

It might be relatively easy to make any human cells produce this toxin. But then you have cells that poison (over time - doesn't matter if its weaker) all the nerves around them ...
Since humans don't have ability to specifically deliver this poison anywhere its not really usefull ...

Comment: I mean I was just gonna have it be distributed in the same method as the slow loris